# How do I count MySQL entries with a HAVING criterion

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions, having

So usually you can just do

```
SELECT COUNT(field.id) FROM table WHERE field.id > 100
```

and COUNT(field) will return the number of entries that has the criterion of field.id > 100

But then what if you what to count entries specified with the HAVING criterion such as

```
SELECT COUNT(field.id), field.id * 10 AS foo FROM table HAVING foo > 100
```

the code wouldn't work in this case....

How do I go about counting entries whose criterion are specified via the HAVING clause?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In your sample **HAVING** is overused. Use **WHERE** or think up another example.

Comment: I can't run either query as-is - they give me a 1140 error for using an aggregate without a `GROUP BY` clause (IE: `COUNT(field.id)`).  Everything appears not to relate to the aggregate at all, just the ability to reference the column alias for comparison...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, `COUNT` works **BEFORE** `HAVING` is applied to the **result set**. So if you need to count their number - you have to wrap your query with another one.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT field.id * 10 AS foo FROM table HAVING foo > 100
)
```

Comment: this is great, although I had to add turn the query to  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT field.id * 10 AS foo FROM table HAVING foo > 100
) AS derived

Comment: @kamikaze_pilot: yup, i forgot that in this case we should give an alias for nested query.

Answer (score 2):

I can't run either query as-is - they give me a 1140 error for "using an aggregate without a GROUP BY clause" (IE: `COUNT(field.id)`). Everything appears not to relate to the aggregate at all, just the ability to reference the column alias for comparison...

The most widely supported means is:

```
SELECT field.id * 10 AS foo 
  FROM table 
 WHERE field.id * 10 > 100
```

MySQL does support referencing a column alias in the `GROUP BY` or `HAVING` clause.  It doesn't require using backticks, but I have seen instances that wouldn't work (non-reserved words) until backticks were present:

```
SELECT field.id * 10 AS foo 
  FROM table 
HAVING `foo` > 100
```

I don't recommend this approach - it's supported on SQL Server, but not Oracle...

The `HAVING` clause is like the `WHERE` clause, the difference is that the `HAVING` clause supports aggregate functions without needing them to be wrapped in a subquery.

Comment: @Martin Smith: Could be, but there was a question recently that wouldn't work unless the alias was in backticks so I'll err to the side of caution.

Comment: btw, your second query will always return empty set, because of `HAVING`

Comment: and to be clear, the **main** difference between `WHERE` and `HAVING` is that `WHERE` works on the physical data level, it works with raw data, and `HAVING` works with complete result set.

Comment: @OMG - If I try `SELECT count(id), id+1 as foo FROM mytable` it just returns a single row result set which seems to have the top row in the table. So I guess unless that `id` in the single row happens to be >99 then nothing will be returned.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: nope, they are not.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: create table with one column `a` and add 3 records: 1, 2, 3. `WHERE a > 1` vs `HAVING` equivalent and `WHERE a > 2` vs `HAVING` one will return different results.

Comment: @zerkms: I tested using a table with 105 records, numbered 1-105.  After omitting the COUNT in the original query due to the MySQL 1140 error, I get identical result sets from both versions of the queries I posted: 95 records, with a `foo` value of 100 to 1050, incrementing by 10.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: it is impossible. for values more than first row in a table (which is selected when we write `COUNT(*), foo`) `HAVING` should return empty set. And it does on my mysql 5.1. "After omitting the COUNT" --- yes, because it is the key reason of why you get empty set otherwise.

Comment: @zerkms: if you tested it, then you'd know MySQL would return a 1140 error for trying to use an aggregate without a group by clause.  That's not an empty result set...

Comment: @OMG-  I don't get this error either. I Think it might be dependant on [this sql mode option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)?

Comment: i tested it and it works for me. seems like you have changed some server mode options.

Answer (score 1):

DISCLAIMER - I've only tested this on SQL Server

HAVING in this case will only perform any aggregate queries over the entire returned set.  First of all, you can't run

```
SELECT COUNT(field.id), field.id * 10 AS foo FROM table HAVING foo > 100
```

because field.id is not contained in a clause that defines a group or an aggregate function; it just doesn't compile.

With that said, the following SQL -

```
SELECT COUNT(field.id) FROM table HAVING COUNT(field.id) > 100
```

will return the count of rows in the table if **the count** is greater than 100.  If it's not, you'll get no result.

Do you have a specific problem in mind?  What are you trying to count?